# Extract column from multiple csv files and merge into new data frame in R

Tags: r, csv

I want to extract column called `X1` out of 168 different .csv files, called `table3_2`, `table3_3`, `table3_4`, `table3_5`..., `table3_168`, all held in one folder (folder1). Then, merge into one new df. Contents of the column is factor.

Trying this code but can't get it to work.

```
folder1 <- "folder1"
folder2 <- "folder2" # destination folder

write_to <- function(file.name) {
file.name <- paste0(tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(file.name)), ".csv")
df <- read.csv(paste(folder1, file.name, sep = "/"), header = FALSE, sep = "/")[X1]
write.csv(df, file = past(folder2, file.name, sep= "/"))
}

files <- list.files(path = folder1, pattern = "*.csv")

lapply(X = paste(folder1, files, sep= "/"), write_to)
```

This comes up with the error:

> Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
> In addition: warning message:
> In file(file, "rt") :
> cannot often file `folder1/folder1.csv`: No such file or directory

So, I am not calling in the correct names of the table, and maybe not directing R to the correct folder (I've set the wd to folder1).

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: You said you set the wd to folder1. R then could not find folder1 anymore because you were already in it. If both folder1 and folder2 have the same parent folder, then you should set your wd to that one. Otherwise, you could try using their absolute paths.

Comment: Thank you, that's really helpful to know

Answer (score 0):

There are a few minor issues that stand out, e.g. you have a typo in `file = past(folder2, file.name, sep= "/")` (should be `paste()` not `past()`) but perhaps a simpler approach would suit, e.g. using [vroom](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/05/vroom-1-0-0/):

```
library(vroom)

files <- fs::dir_ls(glob = "table3_*csv")
data <- vroom(files, id = "ID", col_select = c(ID, X1))
data

vroom_write(data, file = "~/xx/folder2/new_df.csv")
# replace "xx" with your path
```

Does this approach solve your problem?

Comment: Hi, thanks so much. It looks like the first part is working but I am running into an error comment for the vroom_write line. vroom_write(data, file = "~/P:/Project3/Analysis/folder1?new_df.csv") gives the error Error in vroom_write data,... unused argument (file = "~P..) Do you know what I am doing wrong with the file path? I have set Analysis as the wd here?

Comment: Sorry, the file path I set was "~/P:/Project3/Analysis/folder1/new_df.csv"

Comment: That looks to me like a full path, so try dropping the tilde at the start (i.e. `file = "P:/Project3/Analysis/folder1/new_df.csv"`)